# Different behaviour of eax compared to other registers

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I've written a small assembly snippet (Gas, 32 bit) that takes a command-line argument, counts its characters and prints the string if it has a certain length (just for debugging purposes). I'm relatively new to assembly, so I'm pretty sure there is something I miss here because I get different behaviour when I store the string in eax compared to, for instance, ecx, edx or esi.

Here is the snippet. When you replace esi with eax, the loop is entered only twice no matter how long the string is, hence the counter (ebx) is always 1. With esi or other registers, everything seems to work fine.

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    0(%ebp), %eax   # get argc
    cmpl    $2, %eax        # ensure argc == 2
    jne     _exit           
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax   # get argv[1]
    movl    $0, %ebx        # set counter to 0
_begin_loop:
    movb    (%eax), %al     # load a character into %al
    cmpb    $0, %al         # see if \0 is reached
    je      _end_loop       # exit loop if at end of string
    incl    %ebc            # increment counter
    incl    %eax            # advance string
    jmp     _begin_loop
_end_loop:
    cmpl    $6, %ebx        # print the string if it's six characters long
    jne     _exit
    movl    $4, %eax        # prepare for output
    movl    $1, %ebx
    movl    8(%ebp), %ecx)
    movl    $6, %edx
    int     0x80
_exit:
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    $0, %ebx
    int     0x80
```

Can anybody give me a hint about what I'm doing wrong/misunderstanding?

Greets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `al` register is really the lowest 8 bits of the `eax` register. So, the instruction `movb (%eax), %al` destroys the lowest 8 bits of `eax`, that is your pointer.

As a general advice, learn to use a debugger to step through your code and spot where the computer does something different from what you expect.

EDIT: there are some trivial syntax errors in the posted code (such as `ebc` instead of `ebx`), but I assume some copying error since you say otherwise it works.

Comment: Full ack. Thanks for the explanation, of course this is the right answer.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that x86's registers are not all the same. Some can do things that other's can't. This is not the case for every CPU architecture. For example, the Motorola 68000's data registers `D0` through `D7` are all equally capable of doing the same tasks. That being said, it's not really relevant to what's going on here, but it's important to remember for x86.