# Assembly EAX register resetting without reason

Tags: c, assembly

I have the following assembly code:

```
; File: strrev.asm
; A subroutine called from C programs.
; Parameters: string A
; Result: String is reversed and returned.


    SECTION .text
    global strrev
_strrev: nop
strrev:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; registers ebx,esi, and edi must be saved if used
    push ebx
    push edi

    xor esi, esi    
    xor eax, eax
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]    ; load the start of the array into ecx
    jecxz   end     ; jump if [ecx] is zero
    mov edi, ecx

reverseLoop:
    cmp byte[edi], 0
    je  reverseLoop_1
    inc     edi 
    inc eax
    jmp reverseLoop



reverseLoop_1:

    mov esi, edi    ;move end of array into esi
    mov edi, ecx    ;reset start of array to edi

reverseLoop_2:
    mov al, [esi]
    mov bl, [edi]
    mov     [esi], bl
    mov [edi], al
    inc edi
    dec esi
    dec eax
    jnz reverseLoop_2

end:
    pop edi     ; restore registers
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp    ; take down stack frame
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Which works fine until you start looping through reverseLoop_2. Using gdb, eax is listed as being 11, which it should be (this is the length of the string I passed in through a separate c program). This is show in the debugger as:

```
Breakpoint 2, reverseLoop_2 () at strrev.asm:40
40      mov al, [esi]
(gdb) display $eax
1: $eax = 11
```

However, if I step through the program to the next line, it resets to 0.

```
(gdb) next
41      mov bl, [edi]
1: $eax = 0
```

I need eax to be preserved since its the one keeping track of how many times reverseLoop_2 needs to loop. Why is it resetting to 0 after the call to mov?

Comment: You're clobbering al and thus eax. See my answer on your other question ;)

Comment: Changing the register to cl worked. However the returned string to the main of the c program is "", or an empty string. Do I need to move either edi or esi into the ebp register before returning control to the c file?

Comment: You shouldn't need to store anything into EBP. Sounds like you didn't get the initial or terminating condition of the character swapping loop quite right. Compare your code with https://gist.github.com/scottt/5524997

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different behaviour of eax compared to other registers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562950/different-behaviour-of-eax-compared-to-other-registers)

Comment: Scott: I compared my code to yours and saw the error i made. However, my output comes out as: str1 reversed: "dlroW " where the boxes are bytes printed out as is. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `eax` as a loop counter, you shouldn't write to it inside the loop :

```
reverseLoop_2:
  mov al, [esi]
```

Remember that `al` is the least significant byte of `eax` :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
    mov eax, address of your string

    push esi
    push edi

    mov edi, eax
    mov esi, eax

    ; find end of string
    sub ecx, ecx
    not ecx
    sub al, al
    cld
    repne   scasb

    ; points to the byte after '0x00'
    dec edi
    dec edi

            ; main loop will swap the first with the last byte
            ; and increase/decrease the pointer until the cross each other

_loop:
    cmp esi, edi   ; if both pointers meet, we are done
    jg _done

    mov al, [edi]
    mov bl, [esi]
    mov [esi], al
    mov [edi], bl

    inc esi
    dec edi

    jmp _loop

_done:
    pop edi
    pop esi
```