# Calling assembly code with C, errors in output

Tags: c, string, assembly

I am working on a program in C that takes in a string and prints out the same string reversed by calling a function written in assembly.

My C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// These functions will be implemented in assembly:
//
void strrev(char *str) ;

int main(){
    char *str1;
    str1 = strdup("Hello World");
    strrev(str1);
    printf("str1 reversed: \"%s\"\n", str1) ;
    free(str1);
    return 0;
}
```

And my .asm file is:

```
; File: strrev.asm
; A subroutine called from C programs.
; Parameters: string A
; Result: String is reversed and returned.


    SECTION .text
    global strrev
_strrev: nop
strrev:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; registers ebx,esi, and edi must be saved if used
    push ebx
    push edi

    xor esi, esi    
    xor eax, eax
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]    ; load the start of the array into ecx
    jecxz   end     ; jump if [ecx] is zero
    ;mov    edi, ecx


mainLoop:
    add     eax, 1  ;inc eax would work as well
    add ecx, 1  
    mov dl, [ecx]
    cmp     dl, 0   ; compare current ecx with 0
    je  reverseLoop ;if ecx is 0, we are done
    jmp mainLoop    ;if ecx isnt 0, keep looping

reverseLoop:
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8]    ;reload the start of the arrary into ecx
    mov esi, ecx    ; esi poinst to start of array
    add ecx, eax
    mov edi, ecx
    dec edi     ;edi points to end of array
    shr eax, 1      ;eax is the count
    jz  end     ;if string is 0 or 1 chars long, jump to end

reverseLoop_1:

    mov cl, [esi]   ;load start of array into cl
    mov bl, [edi]   ;load end of array into bl
    mov [esi], bl   ;swap
    mov [edi], al   
    inc esi
    dec edi
    dec eax     ;loop
    jnz reverseLoop_1

end:
    pop     edi     ;restore registers
    pop     ebx         
    mov esp, ebp    ;take down stack frame
    pop ebp
    ret
```

The program runs successfully, but the output is:

```
str1 reversed: "dlroW "
```

Where after the first word, the second part "Hello" is printed as bytes (5 squares with numbers in each corner). What would cause this?

Comment: Consider using a debugger and step by step into each machine instruction of your assembler routine. I.e. `si` command to `gdb`

Comment: I am currently using gdb, and it is returning the string as reversed, but only the "World" in "Hello World" is readable.

Comment: And I feel silly, the error was a simple typo on line 47 where "al" should have been "cl." Sorry about that

Comment: I posted a working version here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399100/assembly-eax-register-resetting-without-reason/16400420#16400420

Answer (score 1):

```
reverseLoop:
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8]    ;reload the start of the arrary into ecx
    mov esi, ecx    ; esi points to start of array
    add ecx, eax    ;
    mov edi, ecx    ;
    dec edi         ;edi points to end of array
    shr eax, 1      ;eax is the count
    jz  end         ;if string is 0 or 1 chars long, jump to end

reverseLoop_1:
    mov cl, [esi]   ;load start of array into cl
    mov bl, [edi]   ;load end of array into bl
    mov [esi], bl   ;swap
    mov [edi], al   ; AL?!? Should it not be CL?
    inc esi         ;
    dec edi         ; 
    dec eax         ;loop
    jnz reverseLoop_1
```

In the above, you read in CL, but then store AL.

I'd do it like this, and do without the check on eax altogether:

```
    mov edi, ecx    ;
    dec edi         ;edi points to end of array
reverseLoop_1:
    cmp esi, edi    ; when esi >= edi we're done.
    jae finished    ; 
    mov cl, [esi]   ;load start of array into cl
    mov bl, [edi]   ;load end of array into bl
    mov [esi], bl   ;swap
    mov [edi], cl   ;
    inc esi         ;
    dec edi         ;
    jmp reverseLoop_1
 finished:
```

Comment: as the length eax is divided by 2 by shifting it to right, the swapping is done for the half of string only and so the logic is correct in that way.

Comment: Yes, I had corrected the post almost immediately - but you were quicker :-)

Answer (score 1):

You gave

```
mov [edi], al
```

instead of

```
mov [edi], cl
```

in `reverseLoop_1`

Answer (score 0):

`shr eax, 1      ;eax is the count` shoud be `sub ...`?  i.e. subtract 1, not divide by 2.

Comment: I made that same error :-) -- he is swapping, so he needs to do it N/2 times. Otherwise, he'd swap each byte twice, and get the original string again.